# Javascript Yii: Session script

Tags: php, image, session, frameworks, yii

Okay, so basically whenever someone gets on the site the icons are all the same color (White) I want this code to do the follow thing : Whenever someone goes to another page (by clicking on one of the other icons) the icon of the page where he is going should have a different color (blue, this is done by loading another image) but only that page, this should also stay whenever he refreshes the page?
This is the current code that I have for a single icon, its not working yet and im not sure what is wrong..

```
<?php Yii::app()->session['/home'] = '1';
  $home = Yii::app()->session['/home'];
  //echo Yii::app()->session['home']; // Prints "value"
  if (!empty($home)){ ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index")."/home"; ?>">
        <img src='<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' width='<?php echo $iconsize;?>' height='<?php echo $iconsize;?>'/></a>
    <?php
    } 
    else{?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index")."/home1"  ?>">
        <img src='<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home1.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' width='<?php echo $iconsize;?>' height='<?php echo $iconsize;?>'/></a>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. But `Yii::app()->request->getUrl()` will give the the current URL. You could test your URL and see if you want to add a certain class (`.blue-icon`) to your `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ivo; I think it would be best to do this using CSS classes. You would have the default CSS class have a background image of home1.png, and the blue one have a background image of home.png. If I were doing this, I would use CSS sprites as well.

But, working with what you've got. Here's one way to do it in Yii:

```
<?php
  // Get the current URI
  $currentUri = Yii::app()->request->requestUri;

  if($currentUri == '/admin/survey/sa/index'){

?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index")."/home1"  ?>">
    <img src='<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home1.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' width='<?php echo $iconsize;?>' height='<?php echo $iconsize;?>'/>
  </a>

<?php

  }else{

?>
  <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl("/admin/survey/sa/index")."/home1"  ?>">
    <img src='<?php echo $sImageURL;?>home1.png' alt='<?php $clang->eT("Default administration page");?>' width='<?php echo $iconsize;?>' height='<?php echo $iconsize;?>'/>
  </a>

<?php

  }
?>
```

For your other icons you can then reuse the `$currentUri` variable. You don't need to set any sessions. When you refresh the page the icon will still remain colored.